# Add Role to Existing User in Azure AD B2C using Graph SDK

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We are using GRAPH SDK to manage users In Azure AD B2C.
We have been able to create an user account and now want to assign a role to the user.
We have referred the documentation but not able to find the way forward.
Is there a way we can assign role to a user using Graph SDK

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/

Answer (score 2):

Azure AD B2C does not really support roles out of the box sadly. There are a couple of ways to do this. If you want to add the roles to your token on sign-in, then you will have to use custom policies and an API call (or Azure Function) to add roles to your claims. If you are new to custom policies, [I highly recommend reading the official documentation on custom policies first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview).

If you only want to manage roles without adding them to your token on sign-in. You can create Security groups in your ActiveDirectory (In the same directory as your B2C tenant). This should look something like this.
[image]
You can then use the [Get Groups call.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or [list memberOf call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
GET /groups/{id}
GET /me/memberOf
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/memberOf
```

Ofcourse you can also [add users to the groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
POST /groups/{group-id}/members/$ref
```

If you do want to add the roles to your token on sign-in, I personally used the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9qN6QqnxQ8 This uses an Azure function but you can also use your own API if you want to.

IMPORTANT: You cannot test calls to your own API with localhost in custom policies, so make sure to make it available with something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

I will describe the steps as well: First add the role (or roles) ClaimTypeReferenceId to your SignUp.xml

```xml
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        Other claims
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="role" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

In the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml add the claimtype role (or roles)

```xml
 <ClaimType Id="role">
    <DisplayName>Role</DisplayName>
    <DataType>stringCollection</DataType> <!-- or string if you only want 1 role -->
 </ClaimType>
```

Add the Rest API call to your TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml. This sets the Parameters of your API call to an email address which you have received from the sign-in, and it expects a role as a result.

```xml
 <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetProfile">
          <DisplayName>Get user extended profile Azure Function web hook</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <!-- Set the ServiceUrl with your own REST API endpoint -->
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://functions.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerGetRoles?code=YOURCODE</Item> <!-- TODO CHANGE THIS URL to your own-->
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="emails" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="role" PartnerClaimType="role"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Lastly, add the GetRoleData TechnicalProfile to your second to last OrchestrationStep

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GetRoleData" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-GetProfile" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="11" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
```

For testing I created an Azure Function with the following code in C#. In this example I just put it hard coded. But you could make a call to the graph API from here.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string[] roles = {"Admin", "Employee"};
    var adminrole = new {
        role = roles
    };

    return new OkObjectResult(adminrole);
}

// string email = req.Query["email"];

    // string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    // dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    // email = email ?? data?.email;
```

Your token should now contain the roles.

```json
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "H-0"
}.{
  "iss": "https://demo.b2clogin.com/9729/v2.0/",
  "exp": 164,
  "nbf": 1634,
  "aud": "4a12ea396",
  "given_name": "Tim C",
  "family_name": "C",
  "name": "Tim",
  "idp": "google.com",
  "sub": "adc1",
  "role": [
    "Admin",
    "Employee"
  ],
  "scp": "demo.write demo.read",
  "ver": "1.0",
}.[Signature]
```